# HOW TO EXPORT/ IMPORT DB FROM SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need to export the db including all the tables from `SQL Server` and then to import it to another computer with `SQL Server.`
I tried to do:

```
tasks-> generate scripts
```

But when I tried to import this db 
by attach he doesn't recognize this file.
how should i do it correctly?
we did our project on my friend computer but i want to get it for myself to...

Answer (score 1):

What you tried is to generate the scripts in order to create the database structure (if you want to use these scripts you need to execute them from SQL Management Studio on your other computer). That's a good solution if you only want to create the database structure on another computer.

If you want to restore the database on another computer with all the structure and data of your database, right-click on your database from **SQL Management Studio -> Tasks -> Back Up**.

After creating a backup of your database you simply need to copy the generated file to another computer and proceed the restore process.

Here is a link that explains the entire process: [Create a Full Database Backup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187510.aspx)

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Backup\Restore technique to make exact copy of your database, But like you said, you only want your tables to be transferred so you can use '**SQL Server Import Export Wizard**' for the same.
Right Click on db -> tasks -> Export data
Using above option you can store all data into a flat file also and take that flat file to destination and import the same.